# View Release Notes across multiple versions of MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm upgrading from MATLAB R2007 to R2010b. The Release Notes section of the documentation for R2010b includes, I assume, only what is new in R2010b with respect to version R2010a. So I may be missing features introduced in versions between R2007 and R2010a.

Is there a document that contains all accumulated changes (new features) across a wide range of versions? Preferably covering from R2007 to R2013a.

Comment: Are you sure you want to update to 2010b? That way you are even outdated after updating. Note that I recently converted quite some code from 2007b to 2013b and this can typically be done with very minimal effort (if you only care about errors, not mlint improvement suggestions)

Comment: Yes, but 2010b is the latest I have on hand right now. Besides, the Ribbon and Word-like look of 2013b does not appeal to me :-)

Comment: [This page](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility) doesn't list everything, but it does list the major changes in each version - the greatest hits. I find it quite useful compared to Matlab's nested mess.

Comment: @horchler That's a nice summary, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

R2010b - R2013a: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html

R14SP2 - R2010b: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes-older.html

Hope that helps!

PS I believe you need to have a (free) MathWorks Account on the website in order to view documentation for a non-current release.