# How can I check since which Matlab version a function exists?

Tags: matlab, function, backwards-compatibility

It was [impossible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152699) in 2007, but is there now a way to check which Matlab versions a function exists for?

For example, in Wolfram Mathematica, the documentation indicates in which version the function was released: e.g. the [GapPenalty() documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GapPenalty.html) mentions "*New in 7*".

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this programmatically within the Matlab environment or are you looking for an online resource?

Comment: Programmatically is better but online resource is fine too.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102886/view-release-notes-across-multiple-versions-of-matlab

Comment: Though it doesn't have everything, I've found this summary of [Matlab version compatibility](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility) useful in the past.

Comment: Thank you both, ideally I would like to have a list of all functions present in all official toolboxes indicating in which MATLAB version they were released (and whether they have been deprecated since then), without having to look at the release notes of each toolbox.

Comment: I'd like to see such a thing too. The MathWorks really should be the ones to do it but they probably never will. Sounds like a good idea for a collaborative open source project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab : how to know in which release a function was implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324062/matlab-how-to-know-in-which-release-a-function-was-implemented)

Comment: @ThierryDalon true but the question you linked to was asked later, and your answer here tops the answers in the linked question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the FEX function [when](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54483-when-when-a-function-was-introduced-by-matlab).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to the release-notes page for some useful information.

For example.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013b/stats/release-notes.html

Then do a search in web page.

Hope this helps.