# Matlab : how to know in which release a function was implemented?

Tags: matlab

Let's take this example : I saw the function "parfeval" in Matlab's online documentation, but it seems this function wasn't included yet in my matlab version (R2011b) since it tells me :

```
>> parfeval
Undefined function or variable 'parfeval'.
```

So how do you find the date when a function was implemented in matlab (or the corresponding matlab release) ?
The question isn't just about "parfeval" obviously, and it's probably very simple, sorry about that, but I couldn't find the answer. I feel it's better to leave a trace for those who will meet the same problem later.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: As far as I know, there is no simple way. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778832/ (and other related questions).

Comment: You have [this site](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/release-notes.html) containing all release notes. It doesn't have a search function so it's quite cumbersome to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I know the question is general, but for the specific case with `parfor`: Do you know if you have the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/help/distcomp/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks guys. In my particular case, I can use parfor but not parfeval so it seems I have the toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a mathworks account with a full license attached, you can use the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/doc-archives.html) . If no documentation exists, the function was not present.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I accept this answer but of course we would all prefer seeing this info in a glance in any function description in the on-line documentation.