# Determining the history of a built in MATLAB function between different versions?

Tags: matlab, function

Is there a complete list of changes made for each given built in function between versions and a record of a functions first incorporation into the MATLAB environment?

Essentially I am writing documents to accompany my work and I rely on some functions only available in newer versions (e.g. polarhistogram).

This is not a duplicate of previously asked questions as I am looking for changes listed for a specific function not MATLAB as a whole. It should be also noted that the suggested duplicates were asked 3 years ago, and as such a list could have been compiled subsequently.

Related topics:

[How can I check since which Matlab version a function exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778832/how-can-i-check-since-which-matlab-version-a-function-exists)

[View Release Notes across multiple versions of MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102886/view-release-notes-across-multiple-versions-of-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no comprehensive list of the functions that were introduced and the changes. The Release Notes for each new release are likely the best place to find that detailed information. The [Online Release Notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) site is actually fully searchable and filterable by release number as well as filtering for incompatibilities.

[image]

In general though, in order to determine when a function was introduced, you can look at the lower left hand corner of the online documentation and it will indicate the first release in which that function was available.

[image]

If you want to automate this, there is a FEX submission called [`when`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54483-when-when-a-function-was-introduced-by-matlab) which will programmatically go and fetch this information.

Comment: That is as much as I suspected. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Sadly, the online release notes only go back five years. [If you need older documention, apparently the only way is to contact customer support](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1721995-where-can-i-find-the-documentation-for-older-releases-of-matlab).